Python MongoDB MagicMock with monkeypatch Unit Test for Assigning Client, Db and Collection
I am working in Python on a Windows system, and I am new to Python and its associated unit testing, and enjoying the learning!
I need unit test coverage for my open_collection method and I am struggling with
my mock of the MongoClient, subsequent call to the open_collection method and getting the expected name of the resultant collection. I know I must be missing something extremely simple and I have done much searching on the internet and found many different things to try, but none matching my exact requirements.
The main issue is this: after I do my monkeypatch setattr with my MagicMock of the client, and call my open_collection method passing in a name of 'test', the instance's collection's object name is:
"MagicMock name='mock.getitem().getitem().name' id='2686909818128'>"
This post is the closest I have gotten to my issue, and I tried some of the things mentioned, event though the scenarios don't exactly meet mine, but no success there:
https://adil.medium.com/how-to-fix-returning-magicmock-object-instead-of-return-value-b262cc76abdd
I have tried setting other properties/attributes in my mock before passing to my open_collection method, but nothing is represented in the collection from the mock after the return from the call to the open_collection method. Not even the return_value. The return value I see in the instance's collection is:
<MagicMock name='mock.__getitem__().__getitem__()()' id='2686909823952'>

I appreciate your assistance!
class Common():
collection = {}
data = {}

def open_collection(self, name):
    if 'MONGO_URL' in os.environ:
        db_name = "testDB"
        client = MongoClient(os.environ['MONGO_URL'])
        db_object = client[db_name]
        self.collection = db_object[name]
    else:
        print("Environment variable MONGO_URL not set! Exiting.")
        sys.exit(0)

And the test:
def test_open_collection(monkeypatch):
    mock = MagicMock(return_value='rvTest')

    monkeypatch.setattr('pymongo.MongoClient', lambda x: MagicMock(db=MagicMock(collection=lambda x: mock)))
    
    _module = importlib.import_module(API_MODULE)
    _instance = _module.Common()

    _instance.open_collection("test")

    assert _instance.collection.name == 'test'

